# Why does this python generator have no output according to keras?

Tags: python, keras

EDIT: updating all the code to organize this question, same issue and question though.

```
def extract_hypercolumn(model, layer_indexes, instance):
    layers = [model.layers[li].output for li in layer_indexes]
    get_feature = K.function([model.layers[0].input],layers)
    assert instance.shape == (1,3,224,224)
    feature_maps = get_feature([instance])
    hypercolumns = []
    for convmap in feature_maps:
        for fmap in convmap[0]:
            upscaled = sp.misc.imresize(fmap, size=(224, 224),
                                        mode="F", interp='bilinear')
            hypercolumns.append(upscaled)

    return np.asarray(hypercolumns)

def get_arrays(each_file):
    img = color.rgb2lab(io.imread(each_file)[..., :3])
    X = img[:,:,:1]
    y = img[:,:,1:]
    X_rows,X_columns,X_channels=X.shape
    y_rows,y_columns,y_channels=y.shape
    X_channels_first = np.transpose(X,(2,0,1))
    X_sample = np.expand_dims(X_channels_first,axis=0)
    X_3d = np.tile(X_sample,(1,3,1,1))
    hc = extract_hypercolumn(model,[3,8],X_3d)
    hc_expand_dims = np.expand_dims(hc,axis=0)
    y_reshaped = np.reshape(y,(y_rows*y_columns,y_channels))
    classed_pixels_first = KNN.predict_proba(y_reshaped)
    classed_classes_first = np.transpose(classed_pixels_first,(1,0))
    classed_expand_dims = np.expand_dims(classed_classes_first,axis=0)
    print "hypercolumn shape: ",hc_expand_dims.shape,"classified output color shape: ",classed_expand_dims.shape
    return hc_expand_dims,classed_expand_dims


def generate_batch():
    files = glob.glob('../manga-resized/sliced/*.png')
    while True:
        random.shuffle(files)
        for fl in files:
            yield get_arrays(fl)

colorize = Colorize()
colorize.compile(optimizer=sgd,loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=["accuracy"])


colorize.fit_generator(generate_batch(),samples_per_epoch=1,nb_epoch=5)
```

Here is the traceback (using Tensorflow) :

```
    Using TensorFlow backend.
output shape:  (None, 112, 228, 228)
output_shape after reshaped:  (None, 112, 51984)
Epoch 1/5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "load.py", line 152, in <module>
    colorize.fit_generator(generate_batch(),samples_per_epoch=1,nb_epoch=5)
  File "/Users/alex/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 651, in fit_generator
    max_q_size=max_q_size)
  File "/Users/alex/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1358, in fit_generator
    'or (x, y). Found: ' + str(generator_output))
Exception: output of generator should be a tuple (x, y, sample_weight) or (x, y). Found: None
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alex/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/alex/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/Users/alex/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 404, in data_generator_task
    generator_output = next(generator)
StopIteration
```

And using theano - note that here hyper column and the classed labels are successfully printed - it seems like this is closer to working:

UPDATE: it works using theano! Im satisfied. however, the question still stands with tensor flow I guess

Now, when I try:

```
for a, b in generate_batch(): print(a, b)
```

or

```
print list(islice(generate_batch(), 3))
```

EDIT: New development - They work!

This works perfectly at least it prints out numpy arrays rather than erring out. However, the Keras issue remains

This makes me wonder if I am simply running into a limitation of keras - since there is so much preprocessing of the data - feeding the image into VGG, extracting the hyper columns, performing the KNN classification on the labels, etc. The fit generator is trying to get batches but doing a ton of work to do it. Perhaps it is too much so it just sees the return value as empty because it is taking so much memory/bandwidth.

I know tensor flow for instance has an entire queueing system built out for this exact issue. It would be awesome to know if this is what Im experiencing - as opposed to implementation error. Any keras experts out there care to weight in??? :)

Comment: An empty generator would still be iterable, like an empty list, but not None.

Comment: (1) does anything get printed in the for loop in your first code? (2) what do you get from `list(islice(generate_batch_from_hdf5(), 3))`? (3) have you shown the full code of `generate_batch_from_hdf5`?

Comment: 1. Yes on the first iteration, it prints out those shapes like (100, 1, 224, 224) (100, 112, 50176), then Epoch 1/5, then the traceback, ill add that to the question. 2. This seems to work - ill add it as well 3. added to question as well.

Comment: Is your program doing strange stuff with `sys.path`, or just strange stuff in general? The second exception in your traceback seems to be suggesting that `sys.path` is `None`, which doesn't make a whole lot of sense. If the whole interpreter is going wonky (e.g. because you have separate threads doing stuff while it's in the process of shutting down) it might explain the generator breaking too.

Comment: What do you get if you call the generator directly: `for a, b in generate_batch_from_hdf5(): print(a, b)`?

Comment: It gives me an error: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. Ill post the full traceback in the question

Comment: Looks like at one step numpy gets sequence instead of a simple value. Could you show source of the function `generate_batch` as a gist or here? Thx.

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky I have organized and updated all the question code generate_batch is in there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

generator should be infinite (loops through data) in fit_generator.

c.f. [keras documentation on fit_generator](http://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit_generator)

> The generator is expected to loop over its data indefinitely.

Try changing your function `generate_batch` to:

```
def generate_batch():
    files = glob.glob('../manga-resized/sliced/*.png')
    while True:
        random.shuffle(files)
        for fl in files:
            yield get_arrays(fl)
```

Also:

I think the problem of your code comes from the line

```
y_reshaped = (y,(y_rows*y_columns,y_channels))
```

This line doesn't seem to do the reshaping at all. It just create a tuple with 2 elements: the numpy array `y` and the tuple `(y_rows*y_columns,y_channels)`.

I suppose you should write something like

```
y_reshaped = np.reshape(y,(y_rows*y_columns,y_channels))
```

Comment: good find! However, the same issues described above still occur :(

Comment: wow! another good find! Now my print list(islice(generate_batch(), 3)) statement rings back the slice - so it is being yielded. However, the keras error remains :(. I am beginning to wonder if it is a limitation of keras - I realize there is a lot of preprocessing - happening - it runs the image through VGG, performs a KNN classifier on the labels all before feeding it in. Tensorflow for instance has a queuing system built out for this very issue. It would be awesome to know if this was the specific issue that I am running into

Comment: Personnally I use keras with Theano backend which works like a charm. (And I use `fit_generator`, yield, CPU/GPU ...) Have you changed your function `generate_batch`? Can you update your code and trackback output? What are the shapes of `hc` and `classed_classes_first` returned by `get_arrays`?

Comment: I did update generate batch - check updated code in question. Different results for tensor flow and theano..

Comment: I have never used Tensorflow myself. Since you said that the code works for Theano but not for Tensorflow, you might want to check this: since you use VGG pretrained model which has CNN layers, you might need to convert convolution kernel from Theano to Tensorflow, see [this Keras wiki](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/wiki/Converting-convolution-kernels-from-Theano-to-TensorFlow-and-vice-versa) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I met exactly the same problem with theano backend. 
I probe the problem by finding that when I increase the "max_q_size" more, this bug came earlier. That means it is a queue problem and related with the enqueue operation!!!

In fact, in my case,a missing "while True" in the batch_generator incur this bug:when training in an epoch approaching the point that all the trainning samples available in your generator were all loaded in the queue, then the generator will have to enqueue "None" to the queue as the "next_sample" and the fit_generator will finally met this "None" and report the bug you mentioned.